# c# WCF [Simple Injectior] injection pattern

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have seen lots of examples on how to do this, but as I am a newbie to DI, I thought it best to ask a question specifically for my issues. Again, I apologize if this has been asked already.

We have a C# WCF service that is working, but I have recently been asked to implement a DI framework for reuse ability. After looking around I have chosen Simple Injector.

So my service currently compiles and I can view the WSDL from a browser.

To start I have placed the initialization code that sets up the container in a Global.asax file in the Application_Start function. Within this function I have the following code:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WcfOperationLifestyle();
```

followed by my registrations:

```
container.Register<IPersonManager, PersonManager>();
etc....
```

finally, I run:

```
SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);
```

This runs correctly, no errors and I can break point onto the fisrt line above and step through the code.

*I have been told that I should use a different location for the initialization code and not use a global.asax file.* **Not sure if I should change this.**

OK.

When I look at the constructor for the PersonManager class, I am passing an object that also implements the IPersonManager interface.

*I am assuming this is the correct way of doing this.* So as long as the object implements the IPersonManager interface it will be injected in. **Not sure about this either**

Anyway,

I have a class, the code is as follows:

```
public static class AddressRepository
{
    public static void SetAddress(this IRepository<Address> AddressRepository)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And I have tried to set the Simple Injector initialisation for this as follows:

```
container.Register(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Address), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

This does not work. I guess because the AddressRepository does not implement an interface, but the method does.

Is it possible to inject into this method and if so how is it done.

Comment: A DI container can not help you with injecting dependencies into static classes. You should pass in the dependency in the method yourself; you don't need a DI container for that.

Comment: And besides, since your SetAddress method is an extension method, it means that you should already have a reference to `IRepository<Address>` to be able to call `SetAddress` on it. So you should inject `IRepository<Address>` into the constructor of the class that contains the call to `SetAddress`.